In a Bolero app, where to define new variables and functions in a new 'page'?
I created a new Bolero app with the following steps:
dotnet new -i Bolero.Templates
dotnet new bolero-app -o MyApp

In the main.fs file I added code for a new page. Additionally to the default lines I added:
type Page =
    // New page
    | [<EndPoint "/Tax">] Tax

type Model =
    {
        page: Page
        counter: int
// The type personDetails is a record (first name, last name). 
        user: personDetails
    ...
    }

let initModel =
    {
        page = Home
        counter = 0
        user = {
            firstName = "Max"
            lastName = "Meyer"
        }

type Message =
    | SetPage of Page
    | ...
    | GetName
    | SetName of string

let update remote message model =
    let onSignIn = function
        | Some _ -> Cmd.ofMsg GetBooks
        | None -> Cmd.none
    match message with
    | SetPage page ->
        { model with page = page }, Cmd.none
    ....

    | GetName ->
        { model with user = { model.user with firstName = "Berta"} }, Cmd.none
    | SetName fstName ->
        { model with user = { firstName = fstName; lastName = "Meyer"} }, Cmd.none

let taxPage model dispatch =
    Main.Tax()
        .GetName // Error with "FS0039: The type 'Tax' does not define the field, constructor or member 'GetName'"
        .FirstName(model.user.firstName, fun fst -> dispatch (SetUser fst))
        .Elt()

let view model dispatch =
    Main()
        .Menu(concat {
            // New page
            menuItem model Tax "Tax Form"
        })

In the main.html file I added this section:
<template id="Tax">
    <h1 class="title">Tax declaration form</h1>
    <p>
        This is the tax page!
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="fName">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" bind="${FirstName}"/> <br />
        <label for="lName">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" /> <br />
        <button onclick="${GetName}" class="button">Get Name</button>
    </p>
</template>

Whatever I use in Main.Tax(), i.e .GetName or .SetName or .FirstName, I always get the error The type 'Tax' does not define the field, constructor or member 'GetName'"
Where else should I define them?

I have this old repo which perhaps will be of some help to you. It uses an older Bolero of course: https://github.com/BentTranberg/ExploreBolero

So, principally the answer to my question is that my version of Visual Studio (17.9.6) doesn't update or recognize a new variable in the HMTL file. I need to restart VS again.
